# Catchable Fatal Error

Tags: symfony

So, I have two entity Sponsor and TypeSponsor, relied by a ManyToOne relation where Sponsor is the owner.
When I try to get the SponsorType list of a Sponsor given in parameter, I obtain this :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::findBy() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\ppe2\src\NP\SponsorBundle\Controller\SponsorController.php on line 131 and defined

Here is my controller's action :

```
public function voirAction($id){

    // On récupère le sponsor
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $sponsor = $em->getRepository('NPSponsorBundle:Sponsor')->find($id);

    // Si le Sponsor n'existe pas
     if ($sponsor == null) {
         throw $this->createNotFoundException("Le sponsor d'id ".$id." n'existe pas.");
    }

    // On récupérere le contact
    $sponsorContact = $em->getRepository('NPSponsorBundle:Contact')->findBySponsor($sponsor);

    // On récupère la catégorie du sponsor
    $categorie = $em->getRepository("NPSponsorBundle:TypeSponsor")->findBy($sponsor);

    // Appel de la vue
    return $this->render('NPSponsorBundle:Sponsor:voir.html.twig', array(
        'sponsor'           => $sponsor,
        'sponsorContact'    => $sponsorContact,
        'categorie'         => $categorie

    ));
}
```

And here it's my code about the relation :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="NP\SponsorBundle\Entity\TypeSponsor", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $typeSponsor;
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Would be helpful to translate the comments to English, next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call the TypeSponsor repository every time. You should add a `GetTypeSponsor()` to you entity and use it directly

Comment: Thanks for answer but my TypeSponsor entity don't have a sponsory field and it return me this error:

Entity 'NP\SponsorBundle\Entity\TypeSponsor' has no field 'sponsor'. You can therefore not call 'findBySponsor' on the entities' repository

Comment: This not works too because I don't have TypeSponsor field too. In fact my TypeSponsor entity is composed by an id and a name. But my Sponsor one contain an id, a name and a foreign key to my TypeSponsor Entity.

Answer (score 0):

If your entities are connected, for example, via a field in the Sponsor entity named "typeSponsorId", then you should replace this

```
$categorie = $em->getRepository("NPSponsorBundle:TypeSponsor")->findBy($sponsor);
```

with

```
$categorie = $em->getRepository("NPSponsorBundle:TypeSponsor")->find($sponsor->getTypeSponsorId());
```